# Flask app can't seem to find relative parent package at Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, package, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app to Heroku.
When I run it locally, it works fine.
But when I deploy it to Heroku and start the dyno, it crashes.
It seem to have a problem with the relative parent package:
[image]

The project structure is as follows:

[image]

My Procfile is as follows:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-
```

And this is the line it crashes at:

[image]

Why it fails to see that parent package?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not just `import error_handlers`?

Comment: Ok, but inside it there's an import "from app.routes.main import create_response" and I cannot remove the 'from' part from there too, because if I do I get:
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.routes'; 'app' is not a package"